# How to get max salary of 2 employees in each department

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, top-n

How to get max salary of 2 employees in each department in which employee is associated with?

Comment: What database are you using? Don't tag multiple DB's. Also show us what have you done till now.

Comment: Instead of using rownum can we use rank , and if yes please share the query for the same.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt. And remove tags for products not involved.

Comment: @ShivaniGauryan - Rank will give you similar result if all salary in dept are different. But if they are same, they will be assigned same rank. However, row_number will not assign same row_number to same sal. It completely depends of your expectation from the query. Read this [article](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
select * from (
select employee_id,row_number() over (partition by department 
  order by salary desc) as rno 
 from employee
) t
where rno<=2
```